# How to sort text alphabetically in Python?

Tags: python

I would like to sort a text alphabetically in Python. I manage to sort all the words according to their first letters, but when several words have the same first letter, I don't know how. Can anyone help me? Thanks

```
def liste_mots(text:str) -> list:
    x = text.lower()
    L_mots = x.split()
    return L_mots


def tri_alpha(text:str) -> str:
    assert type(text) == str
    
    L_txt = liste_mots(text)
    
    L1 = []
    for mot in L_txt:
        L1.append([ord(mot[j]) for j in range(len(mot))])

    
    for i in range(len(L1)-1):
        for j in range(0, len(L1)-i-1):
            
            if L1[j][0] > L1[j+1][0]:
                L1[j], L1[j+1] = L1[j+1], L1[j]

    return L1


text = "test un je une ja"
print(tri_alpha(text))
```

I convert each letter in Unicode code to sort.

Comment: You could try to create a loop that continues to the next character if the first two are the same, limited by the length of the shortest word and placing the shortest first if both are the same up until that point (e.g. "test" < "testing").

Comment: Actually, when testing around, calling `sort()` on a list of strings already sorts it alphabetically in the way you want. Simply call `L1.sort()` to get the behavior you want.

Comment: I dont get why you convert it to unicode you can compare letters `a<b`, `z>h` etc.

Comment: I think I see a `lower` in there, If you want case-insensitive sorting, then `.sort(key=str.casefold)`.

Comment: Just `sorted(text.split())` should do the trick. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=sorted#sorted

Comment: @noah1400 the fun part of Python is that 'z' > 'h' is True, while 'Z' > 'h' is False.

Comment: I'd suggest that none of the solutions provide an alphabetic sort. Alphabetic sorts are language dependent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyhton is able to sort strings but it sorts function is lower/uppercase sensitive. Anyways there is an easy way around it using a lambda function that turns every letter into lowercase:

Ignoring lower/uppercase:

```
words="asbdd testing Kaeas Asdbbw asdbba"
lista= words.split(" ")
print(sorted(lista, key=lambda s: s.lower()))
#output 
['asbdd', 'asdbba', 'Asdbbw', 'Kaeas', 'testing']
```

without ignoring lower/uppercase:

```
words="asbdd testing Kaeas Asdbbw asdbba"
lista= words.split(" ")
print(sorted(lista))
#output
['Asdbbw', 'Kaeas', 'asbdd', 'asdbba', 'testing']
```

Comment: You can also do this with `key=str.lower` -- no need to wrap it in a `lambda`.  :)

Comment: You are right :) didnt knew that though

Comment: @tetrisprogramming, once you start getting outside of English and Western European languages key=str.lower vs key=str.upper can give very different sort results with the sort orders changing, depending on whether lower or uppercase is used. And for at least one script, uppercasing should be used instead of lowercasing. Python applies a primary weight to all characters. Fundamentally different to how Unicode and CLDR handle collation.

Answer (score 0):

If iterating over the words this way is a requirement, I would adapt noah1400's answer and employing a more efficient bubble sort:

```py
def liste_mots(text:str) -> list:
    return text.lower().split()

def tri_alpha(text:str) -> str:
    assert type(text) == str

    L_txt = liste_mots(text)

    # perform bubble sort on the list of words
    for i in range(len(L_txt)-1):
        for j in range(i+1, len(L_txt)):
            for k in range(min(len(L_txt[i]), len(L_txt[j]))):
                # words in wrong order
                if L_txt[i][k] > L_txt[j][k]:
                    L_txt[i], L_txt[j] = L_txt[j], L_txt[i]
                    break
                # words in right order
                elif L_txt[i][k] < L_txt[j][k]:
                    break
            else:
                # case "testing test"
                if len(L_txt[i]) > len(L_txt[j]):
                    L_txt[i], L_txt[j] = L_txt[j], L_txt[i]

    return L_txt

text = "test un je une ja"
print(tri_alpha(text))
```

Output:

```py
['ja', 'je', 'test', 'un', 'une']
```

Answer (score -1):

you  can create a loop which continues to the next character if the previous two are the same:

```py
def tri_alpha(text:str) -> str:
    assert type(text) == str

    L_txt = liste_mots(text)

    # perform bubble sort on the list of words
    for i in range(len(L_txt)-1):
        for j in range(0, len(L_txt)-i-1):
            # compare the first letter of each word
            if L_txt[j][0] > L_txt[j+1][0]:
                L_txt[j], L_txt[j+1] = L_txt[j+1], L_txt[j]
            # if the first letters are the same, compare the words character by character
            elif L_txt[j][0] == L_txt[j+1][0]:
                k = 1
                while k < min(len(L_txt[j]), len(L_txt[j+1])):
                    if L_txt[j][k] > L_txt[j+1][k]:
                        L_txt[j], L_txt[j+1] = L_txt[j+1], L_txt[j]
                        break
                    elif L_txt[j][k] < L_txt[j+1][k]:
                        break
                    k += 1

    return L_txt
```

Output:

```
['ja', 'je', 'test', 'un', 'une']
```

Comment: You have forgotten to swap the words after the while loop if they are the same up to that point and the shorter one is to the right. This code fails for the sentence `"testing test"`.

Comment: You can compare entire strings, doesn't the loop achieve the same as `if L_txt[j] > L_txt[j+1]`?